# [Meta] Why don't tags auto-complete anymore?

Tags: meta

When asking a question, it used to offer suggestions as I was typing tags.  This is no longer happening.  Was this changed on purpose?  Is it happening for anyone else?

Comment: I have been getting the auto tagging about 50% of the time. I assumed they were tweaking the settings or something over the last couple days.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: It's definitely a user by user issue. Just checked it again, and it works here: http://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/n2j37/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try quitting & restarting your browser. This happened to me - along with the preview pane & editor bar not working.

Comment: I was seeing it yesterday at work and then again at home.  The home PC had to be booted, so the browser was freshly opened.

Comment: Might have been a coincidence for me then.

Answer (score 0):

Hit Ctrl+R twice in a row to completely reload the javascript on the page.  If that doesn't work, you might need to clear your browser cache.

We don't have widespread reports of this.